# Strange experience with subversion

Tags: svn

I first created the `/trunk` on `domain.name`

```
svnadmin create /trunk
svnserve -d -r /trunk
```

Then I tried to connect to `svn://domain.name/trunk`,but it doesn't exists...

So I tried `svn://domain.name/`,this time it works...

Why my repository `/trunk` maps to `/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a repository folder called `trunk` with the first command (the `-r` argument tells svnserve to set the given location as the root.), but this is just the filesystem location of the repository.

I believe svnserve will always seerve the repo as the root folder in the URL (I can't see any options in the man page for overriding this, anyway).

What I think you need to is to create and commit the `trunk` folder into your empty repository (along with your branches and tags folders, should you desire them). My usual tactic is as follows:

On the Server:

```
svnnadmin create repo
svnserve -d -r repo/
```

On the Client:

```
svn co svn://domain.name/ repo/
cd repo
mkdir branches tags trunk
svn add *
svn ci -m "Base directory structure"
```

Then `svn://domain.name/trunk` will be your repository trunk.